# Correct Implementation of Custom UIView into ViewController Programatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I am familiar with using storyboards to construct UI elements in Xcode, but I am only beginning to learn how to make UI programmatically (without a storyboard).

I wanted to know if this is the correct way to implement a UIView into an existing ViewController class.

DetailView (Custom UIView class):

#### .h file (header)

```
@interface DetailView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *ratingView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *tagLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *plotLabel;


@end
```

#### .m file (implementation)

```
- (instancetype)init {

if(self = [super init]){
    // Creating the large movie image
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, 375.0f, 200.0f)];

    // Creating the rating image
    _ratingView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    // Creating the tag Label
    _tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38, 274, 355, 200)];
    self.tagLabel.font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];

    // Creating the plot label
    _plotLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 299, 355, 200)];
    self.plotLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];


    [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self addSubview:self.ratingView];
    [self addSubview:self.tagLabel];
    [self addSubview:self.plotLabel];
}

return self;
}
```

#### View Controller:

Commented code is another way I attempted to implement the DetailView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.detailView = [[DetailView alloc] init];

self.title = self.movie.title;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.detailView.imageView.image =
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.movie.fanArt]]];
//[self.view addSubview:self.detailView.imageView];

[self setRatingImage:self.movie.rating];
//[self.view addSubview:self.detailView.ratingView];


self.detailView.tagLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.detailView.tagLabel.text = self.movie.tagline;
[self.detailView.tagLabel sizeToFit];
//[self.view addSubview:self.detailView.tagLabel];

self.detailView.plotLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.detailView.plotLabel.text = self.movie.plot;
[self.detailView.plotLabel sizeToFit];
//[self.view addSubview:self.detailView.plotLabel];


[self.view addSubview:self.detailView];
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some detail as to why storyboards won't work for you?

Comment: @nhgrif they work perfectly, I am just learning how to do it with code so I have a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. It is curious to do some of the configuration of the subview's within your custom class (e.g. the frames) and other portions (e.g. `numberOfLines` and `sizeToFit`) in the view controller. If I were going to have this `UIView` subclass, then I'd encapsulate all the presentation details within that class. As it is, if the UI isn't quite right, you'll never quite know which class you have to take a look at.
2. It is curious to use `numberOfLines` of zero, but then to use hard-coded `frame` sizes. (Sure, you `sizeToFit`, but don't adjust the origin.) If one label changes size, wouldn't you want to move the other controls accordingly? You might contemplate specifying `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, too.
3. In this day and age of differing device dimensions, it is curious to see hard-coded `frame` sizes at all. I'd probably implement auto layout unless you had some compelling reason not to. And even if I didn't use auto layout, I'd still specify the autosizing masks.
4. I generally give my subviews `weak` references because the process of doing `addSubview` already maintains a strong reference, and it's not clear your really need two strong references. (Clearly, you have to temporarily use a local variable when instantiating the label, if you go this route.)

   Clearly you're not contemplating it at this point, but let's say you ever wanted to do `[self.tagLabel removeFromParentView]`. Would you also want to have to remember to do `self.tagLabel = nil` as well?

   It's not a big deal, but I tend to follow the NIB/storyboard model that I don't generally maintain strong references to subviews: The only strong reference I'd maintain would be to the root view.
5. You're never setting the `frame` for your `ratingView`. I might confirm the clipping and content mode, too.
6. If you're going to have this `UIView` subclass, it doesn't feel like the view controller should be playing around with which image to show in the rating view. The view controller should probably just tell the `UIView` subclass what the rating is, and that subclass should take care of the presentation of the appropriate rating image.
7. Rather than using fixed fonts, if this was an iOS 7+ target, I'd consider using Dynamic Type.
8. If `[NSURL URLWithString:self.movie.fanArt]` is in the local file system, you can get away with doing that main thread, but if it's a remote URL, then *definite* retrieve that image asynchronously.
9. In terms of having custom `UIView` subclass at all, I'm not sure there's enough utility in this subview to warrant a subclass. Perhaps, once you start incorporating the above points, there might be enough substance to make this worth while, but I'm not sure your existing code sample justifies it.